# Fullpage.js: Next and Previous buttons

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have two buttons: `#btn1` and `#btn2`; and I want them to go back and forth when clicked. So `#btn1` must go to previous slide and when I click `#btn2` it goes to the next slide.

I use  [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) for slides.

In documentation says that must me use this

```
$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();
```

But I'm amateur with `Javascript`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add this:

```
$('#button1Id').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
});


$('#button2Id').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
});
```

And better also to use the option `fixedElements` just in case:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    fixedElements: '#button1Id, #button2Id'
});
```

You can read more about the `fixedElements` option in the [fullpage.js docs](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#options).

**UPDATE**

---

If you are using fullpage.js > 2.X then you don't need to use the option `fixedElements`. Just using a wrapper for the plugin and placing the fixed elements outside the wrapper will work fine if you add the fixed positioned styling in your CSS.

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/836/)