# Fullpage.js custom navigation in WordPress using Elementor Pro and OceanWP Full Page

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js, elementor

I'm trying to put together custom navigation for fullscreen.js using two images on a website I've put together using Elementor Pro and OceanWP for a nice single page site.

I'm currently using the two images as links to move to different sections but I would like to have them be sticky and navigate the site without having to duplicate them on each slide.

I have tried using the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269398/fullpage-js-next-and-previous-buttons) but can not get the code to work by using an HTML widget or a custom JavaScript plugin. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this:

1. Gave the images I wanted to use as buttons a css-id in Elementor
   (Previous_Button and Next_Button)
2. Placed an HTML Widget on the page using Elementor
3. Placing the following code in the HTML Widget:

   ```
   <script>
   (function($) {
   $('#Next_Button').click(function(){
       fullpage_api.moveSectionDown();
       });


   $('#Previous_Button').click(function(){
       fullpage_api.moveSectionUp();
       });
   })(jQuery);
   </script>
   ```